# "Then" at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

> You both are really lucky then.

Let's say two people A and B, explains a situation (something bad) to C, and C tells them how lucky they are to escape from that bad situation. Now C responds, "You both are really lucky then."

What C is trying to say is that, as they escaped from a worse situation while many others didn't, they are lucky.

Now, is *then* at the end of the sentence grammatically correct or wrong? My doubt here is whether a sentence can end with *then*.

Comment: "My doubt here is whether a sentence can end with (the word) then."  This is a sentence that ends with then :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word 'then' has many meanings. In some of its meanings, it is perfectly grammatical at the end of a sentence.

For instance, from definition 3.b from the Merriam-Webster online dictionary ([here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/then?show=0&t=1369719322))

> 3.b: according to that : as may be inferred. *'your mind is made up, then?'*

Another example is using this meaning ([here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/then)):

> 1: At that time. *'Come at noon; I'll be ready then.'*

The Macmillan dictionary describes the meaning of the OP's question directly:

> 3.b: As a result. (SPOKEN, used at the end of a question when you think something must be true because of what has just been said.)
>
> *"We went to the same school." "You're old friends then?"*
>
> *You're not angry with me, then?*

This last one was the meaning of 'then' in the OP's post.

Person C means "As a result of what you just told me, I conclude that 'you both are really lucky'."

Answer (score 1):

"Then" in this context means "therefore." So the meaning of C's conclusion is, "You are both very lucky **therefore.**

Comment: You need to move **therefore** to the beginning of the sentence for this to make sense.